# Display:inline for creating a horizontal navigation bar not working

Tags: html, css

I am relatively new to `CSS` and I'm having trouble getting my navigation bar aligned horizontally. I tried the display:inline; function with no success. When using the float:left function, I get all the li aligned horizontally, but in this case, I cannot center it on the page. Also the margin:0 auto; does not do it in this case.

The navigation bar is created via an ul inside a DIV, which is also contained inside a "wrapper div".

Is the problem linked to the various ID selectors used and the nesting of the various elements?

Please find the jsfiddle below for visualisation:

### [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kingleoric/om4692f3/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks, Danny

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="navigation">

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="gallery.html" class="dropdown">GALLERY</a></li>
        <li class="sublinks"> 
             <a href="#">PORTRAITURE</a>
             <a href="#">NATURE</a>
         </li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="blog.html">BLOG</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="ModelReleaseForm.pdf" target="_blank">MODEL RELEASE</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
  ul {
list-style:none;
margin:0px 5px;}

ul li {
display:inline;}

ul li a {
color:#ffffff;
background:#09F;
padding:0px 0px;
margin:0 auto;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:14px;
font-family:'sans open', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
display:block;
width:auto;
height:40px;
line-height:15px;
text-align:center;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
border: 1px solid #560E00;}

ul li a:hover {
color:#cccccc;
background:#06F;
font-weight:bold;
text-decoration:none;
display:block;
width:auto;
text-align:center;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
border: 1px solid #000000;}

ul li.sublinks a {
color:#000000;
background:#f6f6f6;
border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;
font-weight:normal;
text-decoration:none;
display:block;
width:100px;
text-align:center;
margin-top:2px;}

ul li.sublinks a:hover {
color:#000000;
background:#FFEFC6;
font-weight:normal;
text-decoration:none;
display:block;
width:100px;
text-align:center;}

ul li.sublinks {
display:none;}
```

Comment: what do you want to do

Comment: Add display: inline-block; to ul. 
but i think you are using ul/li wrong.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/om4692f3/1/

Comment: Wrong HTML semantics - `li` don't need to be in separate 'ul's

Answer (score 0):

Your `ul` needs `inline-block` and the menu wrapper needs `text-align:center` plus some `width` to make menu center regardless of an ammount of menu items.

I've updated your fiddle here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/om4692f3/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make the the `ul` and `ul li` display `inline-block`. I also added `text-align: center;` to the `#navigation` element.

Here is the working code example on JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hhjfypmt/

Comment: this does the right thing for me:) thank you. I will go through all the other comments as well to see about the various possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You could do as said above, but if you also want to align it to the left/right, you can add a `float:right` (or `left`) instead, to your `ul li`:

```css
ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0px 0px;
}
ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    
}
ul li a {
    color:#ffffff;
    background:#09F;
    padding:0px 0px;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:'sans open', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:auto;
    height:40px;
    line-height:15px;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    border: 1px solid #560E00;
}
ul li a:hover {
    color:#cccccc;
    background:#06F;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:auto;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
ul li.sublinks a {
    color:#000000;
    background:#f6f6f6;
    border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:2px;
}
ul li.sublinks a:hover {
    color:#000000;
    background:#FFEFC6;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
}
ul li.sublinks {
    display:none;
}
/* CSS For Dropdown Menu End */
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="navigation">
        
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        </ul>
        
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown">GALLERY</a></li>
            <li class="sublinks"> 
                 <a href="#">PORTRAITURE</a>
                 <a href="#">NATURE</a>
             </li>
        </ul>
        
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
        </ul>
        
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        </ul>
        
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" target="_blank">MODEL RELEASE</a></li>
        </ul>
        
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
        
    </div>
    
</div>
```